# regular expression error in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
regex = /^[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}$/

regex.test("2A:3G") // is resulting in false as output.
```

It should be true if I am correct?

Comment: I see you have mention as `A-F` and G is out the range.. so it might be resulting false..correct me as I m not that good in regex

Answer (score 7):

`G` isn't in `[0-9A-F]` so no, it shouldn't be true.

You can check that `/^[0-9A-F]{2}:[0-9A-F]{2}$/.test('2A:3F')` is true, so that's the only reason.